# Color values with Reactable

Tags: r, reactable

I am trying to make some conditional coloring for the values. The thing is that I already read some posts here on StackOverflow and in the reactable wiki but none of them are working!

```
reactable(prueba,
          defaultColDef = colDef(
            header = function(value) gsub(".", " ", value, fixed = TRUE),
            cell = function(value) format(value, nsmall = 1),
            align = "center",
            minWidth = 150,
            headerStyle = list(background = "#f7f7f8")
          ),
          bordered = TRUE,
          highlight = TRUE,
          defaultSortOrder = "desc",
          filterable = TRUE, minRows = 20,
          groupBy = "linea",

          columns = list(
            Inventory = colDef(aggregate = "sum"),
            OCC = colDef(aggregate = "mean"),
            Tickets.Vendidos = colDef(aggregate = "sum"),
            Revenue = colDef(aggregate = "sum"),
            RASK = colDef(aggregate = "mean"),
            CASK = colDef(aggregate = "mean"),
            Rating = colDef(aggregate = 'mean'),
            CpS = colDef(aggregate = 'mean'),
            Red.discount = colDef(aggregate = 'sum'),
            PC1 = colDef(aggregate = 'mean'),
            PC1_margin = colDef(aggregate = 'mean'),
            ASP = colDef(aggregate = 'mean')
            )
)
```

this is my code!!! And I wish to add conditions to the OCC column.

I would like for it to be:

RED if
`0 <= OCC < 0.25`
ORANGE if
`0.25 <= OCC < 0.5`
YELLOW if
`0.5 <= OCC < 0.75`
GREEN if
`0.75 <= OCC <= 1`

I tried using this inside my `OCC` column:

```
style = function(value) {
      if (value > 0) {
        color <- "#008000"
      } else if (value < 0) {
        color <- "#e00000"
      } else {
        color <- "#777"
      }
      list(color = color, fontWeight = "bold")
    }
```

but didnt work :(

please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're not still thinking about this, but in case anyone else stumbles here. The nested ifelse isn't elegant but in any case it functions for setting font color.

```
styler <- function(value){
      color <- ifelse(value > 0, "#008000", ifelse(value < 0, "#e00000", ifelse(is.na(value), "#777", NA)))
      list(color = color, fontWeight = "bold")
    }
```

Define the function outside the table, and you can call it like this. (I had two places in the function, value and params$my_comparator, so I could use these throughout).

```
colDef(aggregate = "mean",
    style = function(value){
    styler(value)
})
```